# object variable cannot be referenced correctly in a json template

Tags: json, terraform, azure-logic-apps

I have the below body used in a resource in terraform to deploy logic app:

```
body = jsonencode({
    properties = {
      definition = jsondecode(templatefile(templ.json,
        {
          schedHour     = tostring(var.schedule_hour) #is a string type;
          functUri      = "https://abc"
          reqBody       = jsonencode(var.func_parameters)   #is an object type;
      }))  
      state = "Enabled"
    }
  })
```

The problem is when I want to deploy that JSON template where I reference the reqBody value as below:

```
"inputs": {
        "subscribe": {
          "body": "${reqBody}",
          "method": "POST",
          "uri": "${functUri}"
        },
        "unsubscribe": {}
      }
```

It results the error when I try terraform apply:

```
Error: Error in function call
    
  on ../modules/logic-app/main.tf line 21, in resource "azapi_resource" "logic_app_workflow":
  21:       definition = jsondecode(templatefile(templ.json,
  22:         {
  23:           scheduleHour     = tostring(var.schedule_hour)
  24:           functUri   = "https://abc"
  27:           reqBody      = jsonencode(var.func_parameters)
  28:       }))
    ├────────────────
    │ while calling jsondecode(str)
    │ var.func_parameters is object with 1 attribute "pipeline"
    │ var.schedule_hour is 5

Call to function "jsondecode" failed: invalid character 'p' after object key:value pair.
```

It seems the problem is on that object variable reqBody which is as below defined:

```
variable "func_parameters" {
  type = object({
    pipeline = object({
      calc_date = string
      ....
    })
  })
}
```

I tried move the reqBody param in a separately block called parameters but not working.

For the "uri" : "${fctUri}" works, it's fine referenced and shows what is needed (it is a string), but the problem remains on that object var;
ref: https://github.com/michaelstephensonuk/CodeSnippets/blob/main/LogicApp-Consumption-WithTerraform/Res.LogicApp.Demo-LogicApp-2.tf

I tried with jsondecode for that object var and the error is saying it should be a string;
somehow it requires a string as for the rest variables: I tried with decode for that object

```
on ../modules/logic-app/main.tf line 27, in resource "azapi_resource" "logic_app_workflow":
  27:           requestBody      = jsondecode(var.func_parameters)
    ├────────────────
    │ while calling jsondecode(str)
    │ var.func_parameters is a object
 
Invalid value for "str" parameter: string required.
```

the rest are strings and they works fine;

Answer (score 0):

You have to break your code and add outputs to see what is going on...
all those nested functions are just obscuring the issue, use multiple local variables, like:

```
variable "func_parameters" {
  type = object({
    pipeline = object({
      calc_date = string
    })
  })
  default = {
    pipeline = {
      calc_date = "test"
    }
  }
}
variable "schedule_hour" {
  default = "12"
}

locals {
  data = templatefile("templ.json",
    {
      schedHour = tostring(var.schedule_hour)
      functUri  = "https://abc"
      reqBody   = jsonencode(var.func_parameters)
    }
  )
  body = jsonencode({
    properties = {
      definition = jsondecode(local.data)
      state      = "Enabled"
    }
  })
}

output "test" {
  value = local.data
}
```

the json I'm using:

```
{
    "inputs": {
        "subscribe": {
            "body": "${reqBody}",
            "method": "POST",
            "uri": "${functUri}"
        },
        "unsubscribe": {}
    }
}
```

yes that will error out but we also get some output:

```txt
Changes to Outputs:
  + test = <<-EOT
        {
            "inputs": {
                "subscribe": {
                    "body": "{"pipeline":{"calc_date":"test"}}",
                    "method": "POST",
                    "uri": "https://abc"
                },
                "unsubscribe": {}
            }
        }
    EOT
```

We can see that body is not valid json:
`"body": "{"pipeline":{"calc_date":"test"}}",`
there are unescaped quotes there.

I've seen some cases like that where we need json inside a string, we just need to escape those double quotes, the resulting code will look something like this:
`"body": "{\"pipeline\":{\"calc_date\":\"test\"}}",`

---

To get around the unescaped quotes you need to do:
`replace(jsonencode(var.func_parameters), "\"", "\\\"")`

full code:

```
variable "func_parameters" {
  type = object({
    pipeline = object({
      calc_date = string
    })
  })
  default = {
    pipeline = {
      calc_date = "test"
    }
  }
}
variable "schedule_hour" {
  default = "12"
}

locals {
  data = templatefile("templ.json",
    {
      schedHour = tostring(var.schedule_hour)
      functUri  = "https://abc"
      reqBody   = replace(jsonencode(var.func_parameters), "\"", "\\\"")
    }
  )
  body = jsonencode({
    properties = {
      definition = jsondecode(local.data)
      state      = "Enabled"
    }
  })
}

output "test" {
  value = local.body
}
```

Comment: So, my problem is that I need somehow to convert that object variable to a string to be successfully passed in my json as "body" : "${reqBody}"  #with double quotes and to be a valid json;
There seems to be a problem with that serialization because I use jsonencode for body, decode for definition and again encode for reqBody.

Comment: @be9inn3r I was on the middle of editing the question when you replied... see the the last part

Comment: You're right, it passes and accept to use "body":"${reqBody}" but it makes noise in the portal when I deploy because the result is not same if I use non valid json as "body" : ${reqBody}     #without double quotes wich makes the logic app to be deployed fine and to work as expected.

When I say noise, I refer exclusive to the var reqBody because I can see in the Subscribe Body block content wrong detailed.
if you want to see the below images:
https://postimg.cc/gallery/hzxjn36     -> the right one is that it has the body listed in a good shape indented correctly;

Comment: @be9inn3r I'm not sure I follow ... if you want to use json encode decode functions you need valid json, no way around that! ... if you want some other format just do it entirely with `templatefile`

Comment: I agree with you, I am trying to achieve the result needed using the replace function and to have the json valid. 
But if I use with reqBody   = replace(jsonencode(var.func_parameters), "\"", "\\\""), 
is not deploying the variable object correctly indented and this makes the logic app to crash or runtime too much and will fail. 
if you can see the images from link to see about what I am refering.

Comment: you can try to build the JSON manually in the UI then try a terraform plan and in the difference it should show the correct syntax

Comment: if I am using it with replace, it deploys as:
                        "body": "{\"pipeline\":{\"calculation_date\":\"@variables('calculation_date')\",\"fvalid\":null,\"name\":\"logic-app\",\"prest":{\"api-models\":{\"skipped\":false},\"callback-url\":\"@listCallbackUrl()\",\"instanceId\":\"abc-def\",\"prepare-import-data\":{\"skipped\":false},\"update-webapp\":{\"skipped\":false}},\"staging\":null}}",

so, it introduces \ that which makes noise and also not indent the json.

Comment: for my case the only solution remains to have a bad reference for that object in my json template: "body" : ${reqBody}     #without double quotes -> this being the way how to reference an Object in JSON template.

Answer (score 0):

Generating valid JSON by concatenating strings together is complicated to perform correctly, because JSON expects values to be escaped in a specific way, etc.

If you instead use `jsonencode` to produce the JSON from your template, you can be sure that the result will be valid JSON because Terraform itself will create the JSON string:

```
${jsonencode({
 inputs = {
   subscribe = {
     body   = reqBody
     method = "POST"
     uri    = functUri
   }
   unsubscribe = {}
 }
})}
```

For this template, the entire template is a single interpolation sequence `${ ... }` which contains just a call to [`jsonencode`](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/functions/jsonencode). The result of `jsonencode` is a JSON representation of its argument, and so the template result will be a JSON representation of the result of the Terraform expression passed to that function.

Because `jsonencode` always produces valid JSON, `jsondecode` of that result should therefore always succeed.

Comment: You mean that variable cannot be converted from object to a string? And to be interpolated correctly to the json template?  I’ve tried also to put it separately encoded as data in locals.tf but it has same error output and only works if I reference in json like “body” : ${reqBody} without double quotes for ${reqBody}